# What is the correct spell attack bonus for a cleric casting Guiding Bolt?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, roll20

For a Cleric with Wisdom 16 and Proficiency Bonus 2, if they cast Guiding Bolt, shouldn’t they get an Attack of +5?
From PHB p.58 (Spellcasting Ability).

In Roll20 it seems to only give the Attack as a +2.

Can someone clarify which is correct?

Answer (score 9):

You are correct, the attack bonus should be +5.

Comment: I'm guessing @Snowcrash didn't select the right spellcasting ability (or didn't select his class from the roll20 dropdown)... or roll20 just had/has a bug.

Comment: @V2Blast Roll20 has a number of bugs on their spells. At least when I was using it. Have since left it for Fantasy Grounds mostly because of horrendous lag.